# Disappearing entities in XML fragment with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, html-entities

I'm using Nokogiri to process fragments of XHTML documents, and am running into some behavior I cannot explain or workaround. I'm not sure if it's a bug, or something I don't understand.

Consider the following two lines, showcasing a reduced version of the problem I'm running into:

```
puts Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("&nbsp;<pre>&lt;div>foo&lt;/div></pre>")
puts Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("<pre>&lt;div>foo&lt;/div></pre>")
```

This is the output:

```
<pre>div&gt;foo/div&gt;</pre>
<pre>&lt;div&gt;foo&lt;/div&gt;</pre>
```

The second line is what I expect, but the first one puzzles me. Where did the `&nbsp;` go? Why does its presence cause the `&lt;` to disappear?

Comment: I suspect this is due to `&nbsp;` not being an XML entity (it’s a HTML entity – try using `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment` and compare the result), though I don’t know why it is producing that output. Its presence seems to be throwing off the parsers handling of entities.

Comment: `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment` works for that purpose, but I get other issues, because my document is actually XHTML, so other parts go wrong. There's some svg elements with camelCase attribute names that get turned into lower case if I do that, and the next step in the toolchain, which consumes XML (not html) gets confused). So I either need to find a way for the XML parse to preserve by entities (declaring them if need be) or to make the HTML parse preserve case on attributes. The later sounds more fragile.

Comment: It looks like you can parse a whole document as XML and it will handle the entities correctly as long as the document has the XHTML doctype. There doesn’t seem to be any way of specifying the doctype when parsing a fragment, but you might be able to parse it as a fragment of an existing XHTML document (if you have one already).

Comment: Wrapping it into XHTML boilerplate to form a full document solved it, thanks. Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Based on matt's suggestion, I'm parsing the fragment by wrapping it in a full XHTML file, as that allows Nokogiri to know about the XHTML entities.

```
fragment = "&nbsp;<pre>&lt;div>foo&lt;/div></pre>"
head = <<HERE
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
HERE

foot = <<HERE
</body>
</html>
HERE

puts Nokogiri::XML.parse( head + fragment + foot).css("body").children.to_xml
```

Feels a bit heavy handed, but it works.